# Is there a way to create a web link in an org-mode file which would cause the browser to load a page and then search for a text in it?

Tags: org-mode

Running the command `org-open-at-point` on an external link such as

```
[[./file.txt::foo][Link]]
```

causes the file `file.txt` to be opened in a separate buffer and the cursor to be placed on the first occurrence of the string "foo", if such a search is successful.

Unfortunately the same principle does not apply for a web link such as

```
[[http://site.com::foo][Link]]
```

as the external browser is fed the whole text of the link, in this case `http://site.com::foo`, doing no a posteriori search.

Is there a way to create a web link in an org-mode file which would cause the browser to load a page and then search for a text in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this feature is not about Org. The first example works because the link opens in emacs, and emacs supports search. You can also open a PDF in an external app and jump to a page because the apps support opening on a page. Browsers generally don't support the behavior you described.

If you can script this behavior from outside of Emacs,  for example with apple script or a shell script, then you could have a link open that script with the URL and the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I am not sure how to write a shell script that will do what you say so I'd really appreciate some hints or reference to manuals.  I do knw how to write a shell script, but my main dark spot is how to communicate with the browser via a script.  One or two lines exemplifying this behavour would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends on your OS and browser. On Mac, you'd probably use AppleScript. On Linux, `xdotool` can send keystrokes to arbitrary appliations (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-gui-program). This is now a separate question that you should open on probably a different SE site.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That gives me a very good place to start!  Incidentally I found another satisfactory solution, at least for Chrome, which is to append `#:~:text=<Searchstring>` to your URL and Chrome will open the site and do the search.  For example, the following URL will load your profile page and highlight your gold badge `https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/91/mankoff#:~:text=Famous%20Question`